Configure Wireguard server with NordVPN
I have a Wireguard server running on raspberri pi on port 51821. I want all internet outbound traffic incoming to wg0 to go through NordVPN. But whenever I enable NordVPN I loose internet access  as well as LAN access (on the client only, Pi still has internet). I tried  different technologies and protocols for NordVPN, tried disabling firewall. Nothing helped. Any ideas where I might be loosing connection?
$ nordvpn settings
Technology: NORDLYNX
Firewall: enabled
Firewall Mark: 0xe1f1
Routing: enabled
Analytics: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
Threat Protection Lite: disabled
Notify: disabled
Auto-connect: enabled
IPv6: disabled
Meshnet: disabled
DNS: disabled
LAN Discovery: disabled
Allowlisted ports:
       22 (UDP|TCP)
Allowlisted subnets:
        192.168.1.0/24
        10.24.36.0/24

Nordvpn Off:
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route show table all
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.69 metric 202
10.24.36.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.36.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.69 metric 202
local 10.24.36.1 dev wg0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.24.36.1
broadcast 10.24.36.255 dev wg0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.24.36.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
local 192.168.1.69 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.69
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.69
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wg0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

Nordvpn On:
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0 suppress_ifgroup 57841
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xe1f1 lookup 205
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

$ ip route show table all
default dev nordlynx table 205 scope link
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.69 metric 202
10.24.36.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.36.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.69 metric 202
local 10.5.0.2 dev nordlynx table local proto kernel scope host src 10.5.0.2
local 10.24.36.1 dev wg0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.24.36.1
broadcast 10.24.36.255 dev wg0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.24.36.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
local 192.168.1.69 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.69
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.69

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group 57841 qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:03:6b:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.69/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group 57841 qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:03:6b:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.24.36.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:08:8c:93:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: nordlynx: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.5.0.2/32 scope global nordlynx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Tried:
$ ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 51821 lookup main
$ ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32763:  from all iif lo ipproto udp sport 51821 lookup main
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0 suppress_ifgroup 57841
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xe1f1 lookup 205
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default


I had a similar problem with nordvpn 3.18. If that is your version, try downgrading to 3.17.4.
It was related to how 3.18 started to use interface "groups" and I have not gotten to the bottom of it yet.

Tried that, same issue.

My bet on why you are loosing connection is because you have multiple network interfaces.
Most noteable eth0/wlan0 vs docker0.
Normally you would have that eth0 and wlan0 has an ip address belonging to same network and both have the same standard gateway, so if you did not also have Docker installered then it would be trivial where Wireguard should send the encapsulated traffic in order to get to the Internet.
As far as I remember the way Wireguard encapsulate all traffic is by deleting the default routing rule in the main routing table and creates its own default route in a seperate routing table.
You can see all routing tables installed on your raspberry pi with the command:
ip rule show

However:
Docker has its own network so for obvious reasons you do not want grab all traffic from your LAN and send it always to the VPN connection.
It is only relevant if destination traffic does not belong to any of your local subnets.
Also Wireguard does not know which network interfaces it should use for forwarding when you have access to more than one subnet.
Therefore I am fairly certain you will have to deal with policy based routing, where you base your rules both on where it is coming from and where it has to go.

Let me explain a little about what policy based routing is about:
Output from ip rule show on my server is as follows:
0:      from all lookup local
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

The number on the left is priority and rules are handled from lowest number to highest.
The words from all means literally from any ip address.
So no matter which source ip then we have to lookup all routing tables mentioned above.
The table local contains a list on all connections your machine is directly connected to and is very similar to what you can see after the line starting with 192.168.1.0/24 in your ip -4 ro list table all command.
Regarding the table 220, I cannot remember if it is related to WireGuard or from when I once tunneled a IPv6 subnet from Hurricane Electric to my home LAN, due to no native IPv6 connection at home until this year.
The table main is of course the routing table we use by default when we use commands such as ip route add ... and is very similar to the first 4 lines in your command above.
I have no routes in my default table.
However it is possible to make a rule that applies only when traffic comes from one place, like your 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.
This can be done with a command like:
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table [name].
It is very similar to this arcane example from Linux Documentation Project
So my first place to investigate is what output do you have when you call ip rule show before Wireguard link goes up and what is the content afterwards?
That would be the first hint towards finding out where Wireguard is hiding in the routing tables. :-)

I've added routing table to the question, but I am not familiar with policy based routing yet, so I will need to educate myself on the subject before I can test if that's the problem.

I have added a little more to my answer to give you an idea of what is going on. You will get MANY results when you search for policy based routing on Google. It is a dicipline you will become intimately familiar with if you ever decide to have more than one Internet connection for your LAN. For instance I have a 5G cell phone modem as a failover for my fibre connection, which means I have to take into account where traffic comes from in order to decide where it has to go. And I have to pay attention to both ingress (traffic from Internet) and egress (traffic to Internet).

What do you mean when you say "when wireguard links go up"? When any client establishes a connection? Because then it's only the default stuff
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default```
Or did you mean when I turn the nordvpn on? That I will only be able to tell you when I get back home on Friday, because if do it remotely I loose the connection:)

I ment ofc the the difference between NordVPN being online or not. Isn't that the one providing Wireguard VPN for you? I know they use their own implementation so that messes things up a bit on what I know. But as far as I recall there should be at least two new tables when you turn on NordVPN. Both saying something like fwmark or something. I should experiment a little with my own VPN server in order to give a more qualified answer for you, but alas I do not have time this week.

I've added the tables before and after Nordvpn connection is established. So if I am reading it correctly packets for wireguard go to device wg0 on the rule 10.24.36.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.36.1. But what happens after? Now we have two defaults for outgoing packets. The second default also matches the destinatoin and it has lower metric (202 vs 205). So does it mean the packets go the second route, or am I misreading it?

Lower metric => higher priority, so that rule is matched first.

When you have NordVPN (or any VPN tunnel that effectively made the default route, a.k.a. interface for "Internet traffics") enabled, any replying traffics (I mean like the encapsulated ones and the handshakes) from your wireguard server to the clients would be routed into the NordVPN tunnel, as your clients are "member(s) of the Internet" (unless their communications run over e.g. your home LAN, which is a pretty unlikely case).
Supposed you are using wireguard for NordVPN as well, you'll need an ip rule that is of lower priority (hence higher precedence) that look up the main table for the "original" default route (same one used for the communication between this "server/client" and the NordVPN server) for those traffics. For example, if your own wireguard listens on 51821:
ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 51821 lookup main

Make sure this get run after NordVPN is up (so that it gets the "correct" priority). Also make sure you del the rule at least before NordVPN is ever restarted (and re-added afterwards), otherwise the NordVPN rules will be "stacked" on top of it priority-wise.
This assumes that your wireguard server listens on 0.0.0.0. In other words, the port used by your server (again, e.g. 51821) is not "shared" by different programs. Otherwise you'll need to leverage from in the rule additionally (or maybe even "connmark").

EDIT: Note that if you rely on such a rule, the rp_filter sysctl of the interface (in your case, eth0) that the wireguard traffics come through cannot be 1 (i.e., "strict mode"). I don't really know if it's a bug or something expected though. In my test, only a "host" match (i.e., a to match for a known client endpoint address) would allow it to continue to work with strict mode rp_filter. (Certainly that won't be what you can leverage in most of the real-life scenarios.) Setting FwMark= and matching that in the rule instead won't help either. (Not entirely sure if using a "connmark" approach could make a difference. Too lazy to test that myself.)

If you use e.g. OpenVPN for NordVPN, the above trick will not work since OpenVPN does not leverage ip rule / alternate route table. Instead it either adds a "host route" for the "remote" address (like Endpoint= in wireguard) to the main table, and override the default route by either temporarily replacing it with a new one, or more often, by adding the "def1" routes (0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1). In that case you'll need to create an alternate route table yourself and copy your original default route to it, and use a rule to lookup that table for the wireguard traffics.

Tried adding this rule (see output above). Still no internet on the client.

@Viktor You'll need to update the source NAT / IP masquerading configured for your wireguard subnet as well. (Also packet filtering, if any.) But before that, you may try to confirm that now the clients can at least ping the server (10.24.36.1).

No, the clients can't ping 10.24.36.1 with or without this rule when Nordvpn is up.

@Viktor as well as LAN access what about LAN hosts? (Make sure you test with the rule.) when Nordvpn is up could you ping it when NordVPN is down though
